# Can anyone direct me to examples of Netlogo code for generating neutral landscape models?

Tags: gis, netlogo

Can anyone also point me to netlogo simulation models that interface with GIS layers and/or automated in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to `Netlogo -> File-> Model's Library -> Code Examples -> Extension Examples -> gis`

You will find 2 examples of how to use the GIS extension.

Furthermore, you can see the documentation for the R and GIS extensions online:

R: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/r.html

GIS: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html

Comment: What about random modified cluster method for neutral landscape model simulation in Netlogo?

Comment: I never heard of random modified cluster method. Do you have a wikipedia to look at? Do you mean like k-means clustering? If so, Netlogo -> File -> Model's Library -> Sample Models -> Computer Science -> K-Means Clustering. In the bottom of the Model's library page, you may search for different models.

Comment: modified random cluster is a method for generating neutral landscape models - are you aware of any neutral landscape models that have been implemented in NetLogo?